# MySql User Bank account log

Tags: mysql, logging, graph

I am planning to make a small game where everybody have a bank account. To see their management skills I want to log every hour or day their amount of money and display it as a graph.
Now my question is how can/should I log this with mySql.

I think its not very practically to do this:

`id user  currentMoney  2014.08.22-04  2014.08.22-03  2014.08.22-02  2014.08.22-01`
(after the currentMoney these are columns for every hour) so that every hour 1 column gets created with the currentMoney. I think thats not the right way. There must be a better way. ideally it would be that after one Month it starts from the beginning again and overwrites the old listings but thats only optional.

My second question: Is there a jquery application that can create graphs out of the databse? Or how can i do this?

thanks for helping and sorry for my english skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Populating a database is done by adding *rows*, not columns.

Adding columns is a structural change, and should happen rarely. A change in the structure typically means a change in the application, which implies a new version of the application.

Add rows. Your log table must look like this:

```
balance_history
===============
* user_id
* balance_date
current_balance
```

Sample contents:

```
user_id | balance_date        | current_balance
      1 | 2014-08-22 04:00:00 |            1.00
    ... |                 ... |             ...
      1 | 2014-08-23 12:00:00 |           99.99
      2 | 2014-08-22 04:00:00 |            1.00
    ... |                 ... |             ...
      2 | 2014-08-23 12:00:00 |            1.23
```

To purge old data, all you need to do is `DELETE FROM balance_history WHERE balance_date < [date_of_your_choice]`.

Comment: There are [plenty of libraries to generate graphs](https://www.google.fr/search?q=jquery+graphs). Recommending one would be off-topic here.

Comment: thanks for the answer and it looks good and you sound like you know what you write but isnt there a rule where no primary key is allowed to exist more then one time? I have not very much knowledge about this. i know that a primary key can be a result out of 2 columns but i only know how to do this with Access an not with mysql.

Comment: Yes, only one primary key per table. Yes, MySQL, like any database engine, can handle [composite primary keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html). This was the meaning of the `*` in the above proposed structure.

Comment: Thanks man. I'm still in school learning so I dont know many things that are for you standart.

Comment: @kruben No problem at all, you are asking the right questions.